# mongo - count return no docoument found instead of 0

Tags: mongodb

In SQL query

```
select count(*) from table where id=1
```

would return `0` as result where there isn't any record with such id.

I would like to get exactly the same behavior but in mongo. Unfortunately I can only use aggregate function.

I was trying something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "key": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "s"
  }
])
```

It works but only with records with `key:1` but when this key does not exist there is "no document found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query using `$facet` to create two possible ways: If document exists or if document does not exists.

- First `$facet` to create the two ways
- Into `notFound` way the result will always be `{count: 0}` ; into `found` way there is the `match`
- Then `$replaceRoot` merging results to get desired value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "notFound": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "count": {
              "$const": 0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 1
        }
      ],
      "found": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "key": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$count": "count"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$notFound",
              0
            ]
          },
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$found",
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3ysQbrUb0ko) where key exists and [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DhLPnZrbxwL) where key doesn't exists.

Also I've tested with [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pk5_-l4DDJa) using `$ifNull` instead of `$mergeObjects` and seem works ok too.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working exactly as I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to do it is with the driver code, if you get empty results you make that document `{"count" : 0}` you dont need i think to do anything in the database.

Another solution can be this (replace the 5 with the key value you want)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kHomixiNb8i)

- creates 2 groups the `matched(count>0)` and the not `matched(count=0)`
- sort by `{"count" : -1}`
- take the `first`, if there was a match count will be the one matched,
  else it will be 0

```js
aggregate(
[ {
  "$group" : {
    "_id" : {
      "$cond" : [ {"$eq" : [ "$key", 5 ]}, "$key", "not_match" ]
    },
    "count" : {
      "$sum" : {"$cond" : [ {"$eq" : [ "$key", 5 ]}, 1, 0 ]}
    }
  }
 }, 
 {"$sort" : {"count" : -1}},
 {
  "$group" : {
    "_id" : null,
    "count" : {"$first" : "$count"}
  }
 },
 {"$project" : {"_id" : 0}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using `$facet`,`$project` and when there were no documents to project it was showing undefined, so I used `$ifNull` expression. I've kept zero value for replacement expression value (see the `$ifNull` [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "keyFound": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "key": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$count": "count"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "keyFoundCount": {
        "$ifNull": [
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$keyFound.count",
              0
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[testCodeHere](https://mongoplayground.net/p/URpMiJPqYjM)